# Создание глобального соединения Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, сервер, сеть, клиент-сервер

Подскажите ,пожалуйста, как можно подключить два пк которые не находятся в одной сети между собой. При этом должна быть возможность обмена пакетами.
(Я пробовал использовать сокеты , но как мне объяснили сделать это с помощью них невозможно)

Comment: А кроме сокетов никаких других способов работы из программы  с сетью и не существует. И они тут вообще не причем. У вас же проблема сетевого уровня. И единственный способ решения проблемы обеспечить сеть между этими машинами. А это может достигаться кучей разных способов, вроде использования общих прокси или установления туннелей (обычно vpn) между сетями

Comment: можете подсказать какие библиотеки использовать для этого

Comment: В большинстве случаев это не библиотеки, а средства операционной системы и/или дополнительное программное обеспечение. И для выбора надо знать массу подробностей в виде структуры сетей, вариантов их выхода в интернет, адресации в сети провайдера интернета (наличие реальных ip, NAT) и ОС на обоих пк и маршрутизаторах обеспечивающих выход в интернет

Comment: неужели никто не может помочь.... придется делать конкурс

Comment: Конкурс не поможет. Надо переписать вопрос, дополнив подробностями, о которых я написал выше. Без этого ответить в принципе невозможно, потому что надо будет перечислить десятки способов объединения сетей и к ним заодно приложить пару учебников по сетям, страниц по 500. И при этом можно не угадать и забыть описать тот единственный способ, который будет нужен в вашем конкретном случае